# Does the navigation stack require a map

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to mess around with the ROS navigation stack with a custom robot that I've built. I'm trying to figure out if it can be used to navigate in a previously unknown environment. The [tutorial for setting up a robot to use the nav stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup#Mapping_.28map_server.29) states that a map is not required. But [this page on map building](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/MapBuilding) says that it does requires a static map. Aren't these statements contradictory? Which is true?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168651/does-the-navigation-stack-require-a-map/) by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2014-05-23

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-01-05**:
Any luck on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to drive around on a map you need one (and usually can build one). However, to just somehow drive around for testing you can configure the global costmap the same like the local costmap or just use an empty map. Obviously global planning will only be as good as what you provide it with data, but we've used this setup to quickly test navigation controllers on our robots successfully.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use the navigation stack without any static map , just with set static map for both global and local false and windowing true , then you can get /map data from hector_slam and use it for your navigation .

---

Originally posted by [edwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/18151/edwin/) with karma: 36 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1